# Two Way Sorted/Unsorted Drag Drop with JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I've got a complex drag/drop scenario that I just can't figure out.  What I've come up with is here: jsfiddle.net/aTjMG/2/

On the left, I have a list of names.  On the right, I have a group of teams.  The list on the left should be alphabetized and not sortable.  The user should be able to assign a person to a team by dragging from the list on the left to a team.  The person's assigned to teams should be able to be sorted or moved to another team, or moved back to the unassigned pool.

I am able to move from the unassigned pool on the left to any team.  I can sort the people in the teams.  What I can't figure out from here is:

1. How to move from team to team.
2. How to move from team to unassigned.
3. How to remove the person from their current location when dropped somewhere else
4. How to prevent a person (on a team) from being duplicated when I sort the people

I think the big problem is that I can't figure out how to catch the "drop" of the drag-n-drop to change the unassigned person to assigned.

A kick in the right direction would be appreciated.  An example that does just this would be majorly appreciated!

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QWgRF/) which has sortables & droppables in different lists.

Comment: It's a good example.  Unfortunately, it uses knockout, not jquery UI.

Comment: Made a little more progress ( jsfiddle.net/aTjMG/4/ ).  I can now go from any list to any list and the item isn't cloned.  However, I can't disable sorting on the left without disabled the drag to another list (It may just be that the "sortable" class is not the right class to use here...)

Comment: What is left that is not working? Do you not want them to be able to drag from a team back into the main pool? Or do you not want people to be able to move members up and down in the main pool?

Comment: The latter.  I don't want the user to be able to move the members up and down in the main pool on the left.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly this is really just multiple sorted lists.

Update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aTjMG/8/

The key is simply declaring them all as `sortable` and not messing with `draggable` at all, which is used for more free-form drag and drop.

```
$(function() {
  $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

There is an example of this at the UI docs as well: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists